# lucene.net vs SQL Server In-Memory Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, memory, lucene.net

I have one table while has 10 million records; it has some relational data in another tables as well. I would like to perform more search and few write operations on these tables very frequently.

I am evaluating SQL Server 2014 In-Memory Tables, Full Text Search & Lucene.NET. Apart from this in my web application, I will use odata service to pull the data.

Can you recommend best option for this.

thank you
-nm

Comment: Fast searches rely more on the indexes than on the tables being in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding performance, every suggestion is unsafe. I would go with Lucene, or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) which are very easy to setup and manage. Moreover, they are totally fast search oriented. I am sure that [SQL Server Full Text Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) could be very effective, but I would invest my time on a Lucene based solution.

Hope I helped!